# data and salt required : hashSync

Tags: node.js, hash, bcrypt, salt

i'm trying to hash the password inside the ueserRouter with hashSync to create a signup
the error: data and salt are required
if someone can help how can i declare data and salt in this function

the code below:

const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.post('/signup',expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

```
const newUSer = new User({
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
  password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password)
});
const user = await newUSer.save();
res.send({
  _id: user._id,
  name: user.name,
  email: user.email,
  isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
  token: generateToken(user),
});
```

})
);

Comment: yes exactly the new error shown : User validation failed: password:Cast to Number failed for value "$sdKlfspkdfpsdiezzfqg/dzg/zaEDf/sfGJOAe" (type string) at path "password"    where can i exactly define password as a string

Comment: @JBallin please dude help me with this and thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that i was defining password as a number in `userSchema` so I changed it to string.
Then I made this change in `userRouter`:

```
password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
```

Instead of:

```
password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message:

> data and salt are required

Fix by passing num salt rounds (or generated salt):

```js
hashSync(req.body.password, 10)
```

Source: [npm](https://npm.im/bcrypt)